# How to get already multiple selected in Rails collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection_select but I cannot get the already selected values to appear as such in my view. Does anybody know how to retrieve them ?

`<%= collection_select(:estudiantes, :id, Estudiante.all, :id, :id_campus, {selected: ???}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: 'true'}) %>`

Comment: What tells if an option must be selected or not in your select?

Comment: @SebastianPalma in my case, an option must be selected if it is paired with the model in the joined table. I have three models, clase; estudiante; and clase_estudiante, which is the joined table. If clase4 and estudiante9; and clase4 and estudiante13 are paired in the joined table, it means that clase4 has estudiante9 and estudiante13. Thus, they should be preselected when the menu drops.